# Meaning of the loop & count parameters in the new NodeMCU gpio.pulse module

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to generate two variable-frequency pulse trains to step a pair of stepper motors using an ESP8266. The new gpio.pulse module would appear to be ideal for this but I can't understand some of the info provided in the [NodeMCU documentation](https://nodemcu-firmware.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/gpio/#gpiopulsebuild):

- Count and loop allow simple looping. When a state with count and loop
  is completed, the next state is at loop (provided that count has not
  decremented to zero). The first state is state 1.

I understand that an array of instruction is built from a table but the parameters `count` and `loop` as described are proving difficult to understand.

```
pulser = gpio.pulse.build( {
  { [1] = gpio.HIGH, [2] = gpio.LOW, delay=100000 },
  { [1] = gpio.LOW, [2] = gpio.HIGH, delay=100000, loop=1, count=100, min=90000, max=110000 }
})
```

If I try running the above example given in the docs, gpio2 produces a square wave with a period of 200ms, lasting for 100 cycles (20 seconds). That partly seems to make sense but gpio1 remains low all the time. The example does not describe what to expect.

If I experiment a little just by setting `loop` to 2, both outputs go high and remain high for 10 seconds (when the `pulser:start`callback fires). This leaves me puzzled as to what `loop` is supposed to do?

Comment: We track this at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/2265

Answer (score 1):

The `loop` key is like a goto -- it specifies which the next step should be. If `loop = 1`, then it effectively runs the steps in the following order: 1,2,1,2,1,2,....

However, if `loop=2` then it runs the steps in the order: 1,2,2,2,2,2,

In the example that you give, pin 1 ought to be a square wave with opposite phase to pin 2. The other thing to check is that you configured pin 1 as an output.

I'll try your example tonight and get back to you.....

... time passes ...

I tried

```
gpio.mode(1, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(2, gpio.OUTPUT)

gpio.write(1, gpio.LOW)
gpio.write(2, gpio.LOW)

pulser = gpio.pulse.build( {
  { [1] = gpio.HIGH, [2] = gpio.LOW, delay=250000 },
  { [1] = gpio.LOW, [2] = gpio.HIGH, delay=250000, loop=1, count=20, min=240000, max=260000 }
})

pulser:start(function() print ('done') end)
```

I had the outputs wired up to a couple of LEDs on D1 and D2, they flashed nicely (out of phase).

HOWEVER, it seems that if you don't use gpio.write on the pin at least once, then the pulse output doesn't work. I'll fix the code so that this isn't required. Sorry about that.

Comment: When you describe loop=2 as stepping 1,2,2,2,2,2, it would seem to defeat the object of having any count value because repeated execution of 2 would have no tangible effect on the GPIO output levels - or am I still missing something? I guess, however, that if there were 3 steps then 1,2,3,2,3,2,3... might have some use with loop=2 defined at step 3.